# Displaying Average together with other columns in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to display a list of members which is more than the average of all other members. My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Members
(
    MemberID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    MemberName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    MemberAddress nvarchar(50),
    MemberContact int,
    MemberAge int,
    RegistrationDate nvarchar(50) 
);


--Inserting Values into Members' Table--
INSERT INTO Members(MemberID, MemberName, MemberAddress, MemberContact, MemberAge,RegistrationDate)
VALUES ('MEM01', 'Muhammed Abdul', 'Damansara','01121565987', '34', '20/02/2017');
INSERT INTO Members(MemberID, MemberName, MemberAddress, MemberContact, MemberAge,RegistrationDate)
VALUES ('MEM02', 'Kyle Franklin', 'Kuala Lumpur','01725445807','36', '10/04/2017');
INSERT INTO Members(MemberID, MemberName, MemberAddress, MemberContact, MemberAge,RegistrationDate)
VALUES ('MEM03', 'Albert Derio', 'Shah Alam','01800235613','56','6/03/2017');
INSERT INTO Members(MemberID, MemberName, MemberAddress, MemberContact, MemberAge,RegistrationDate)
VALUES ('MEM04', 'Khaled Ahmad', 'Penang','01602144956','33','9/01/2017');
```

Here's what I tried so far but no luck:

```
SELECT MemberID, MemberName, MemberAge,FROM Members 
(SELECT AVG(Members.MemberAge) AS AverageAge)
WHERE MemberAge>=AverageAge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Members.*,
    (SELECT AVG(MemberAge) FROM Members) AS AverageAge
FROM
    Members
WHERE
    MemberAge > (SELECT AVG(MemberAge) FROM Members)
```

...though this will result in duplicate data in the new `AverageAge` column - a batch query (a query that returns multiple result sets) would be cleaner:

MySQL has implicit variable declaration (unlike T-SQL which requires forward declaration), so you can do this:

```
-- 1. Get the average-age value:
SELECT @averageAge = AVG(MemberAge) FROM Members;

-- 2. Return the average-age value to the database client as a scalar value:
SELECT @averageAge;

-- 3. Query for Members whose age is above-average in a second batch result:
SELECT
    Members.*
FROM
    Members
WHERE
    MemberAge > @averageAge
```